# Alternative to transaction lock

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, oracle, sql-server-2005

In my project i am using begin transaction commit or rollback changes. but this causes lock to the tables in that particular functionality.

So if the any other user does any other functionality those locked table are not available until the transaction is completed.

I want to know if there is any alternative to transaction which insures data security but the tables are not locked out.

Answer (score 2):

No, transactions are **the** way to ensure data consistency in a database.  However they should not generally result in whole tables being "locked out" to other users.  In Oracle, by default, locks are placed on just the rows being updated.

Comment: SQL Server does lock tables, or at least did. Don't know if they've improved that recently. I was uncertain what the OP was asking for, since the question is labelled both Oracle and SS-2005.

Comment: I know SQL Server can "escalate" to table-lvel locks, but presumably this is not the norm or no non-trivial database would ever work would it?  e.g. one user updates an order line and no other order line can be processed in any way until their transaction completes?!

Comment: I know that Tom Kyte in one of his books talks to this, and how row level locking often results in page locks, which can effectively block other SQL, including selects if they need that page. I was really more confused by what OP was asking for based on the tags.

Comment: @DCookie : the system is used wit hboth the platform sql as well as oracle hence i tagged both.. so whatever solution is provided that should work for both. Hope this clears your confusion.

Comment: @DCookie: As you said - row level locking often results in page locks, which can effectively block other SQL.. thats exactly is my problem.